# popen equivalent in XPCOM?

Tags: javascript, xul, xpcom, xulrunner

I'm trying to use `XULRunner` to add a GUI to a command line based program.

One solution would be to use something like popen from the XUL application to interact with the command line program.

My questions:

- Does XPCOM have popen?
- Does XPCOM have enough primitives to create popen?
- Is there another approach that gives access to the standard in/out of
  a process?

PyXPCOM appears to have this capability, but I'd rather not add a dependency if possible.

Answer (score 0):

[edit] It's possible to implement using [js-ctypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes) and in fact someone already did that.

The module is called **subprocess.jsm**, here's the documentation: http://hg.mozilla.org/ipccode/file/tip/readme.txt

(The 2009 version of the answer: not in pure JS, no. It's possible to create a binary XPCOM component and in fact someone did that - see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=68702.)